# changing only height of font

Tags: ios, fonts, font-size, custom-font

Is it possible to change only the height of a font? I imported a custom font of .ttf data type.
So far I am using this code:

```
 let font = UIFont(name: "importedFont", size: 25.0)
 label.font = font
```

EDIT! some clarifications: I don't want to change the width of the text because I am running low on space in x direction.

Comment: no you can not increase the height only, it will take effect on both properties as

Comment: What do you mean by "change only the height"? What are you not wanting to change?

Comment: I don't want to change the width of the text because I am running low on space in x direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alter the layer for the label using affine transforms so that it only scales the text in one direction.

```
label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 4.0) //(x-scale, y-scale)
```

Your question is very unclear so I'm not sure if this will answer it for you.

Comment: It answered it for me. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to scale it only in the positive direction of y? Now it stretches up and down, but I would like it to stretch only down.

Comment: You will need to change the layer's anchor point for that. Take a look at this apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/anchorPoint

Comment: What the hell, I'll just make it easy for you, add this before your transformation code:
`view.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0)`